# Error to import GPy - ImportError: cannot import name 'Tester' from 'numpy.testing'

Tags: python, numpy, gpy

I need help to solve an error when trying to import GPy package. The error is: cannot import name 'Tester' from 'numpy.testing'.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

I tried to downgrade my numpy version to 1.20.0, but it is still happening.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe check source code - maybe they renamed it or moved to other file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and downgrading to 1.24 worked. However, we can see in the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.24/reference/routines.testing.html) that Tester exists at least from 1.16 to 1.24 so 1.20 should do.
Alex.